# Evitar insertar registros duplicados en SQL Server desde DataGridView en Visual Basic

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Tengo los siguientes registros en un datagridview en VB, al momento de exportarlos a SQL lo hace sin ningún problema, pero si le doy dos veces al botón me duplica el registro, como le puedo hacer para valide que ese registro ya existe mediante la columna "Contador"
[image]

al final se encuentra la columna "Contador" que quiero usar como ID único en este caso 83, 84, 85 y así sucesivamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim agregar As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("insert into checada values (@ID, @Trabajador, @Fecha, @Checada, @Terminal)", conexion)
    conexion.Open()

    Dim fila As DataGridViewRow = New DataGridViewRow()


    Try
        For Each fila In DataGridView1.Rows
            agregar.Parameters.Clear()

            agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToDecimal(fila.Cells("Contador").Value))
            agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Trabajador", Convert.ToDecimal(fila.Cells("Trabajador").Value))
            agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", Convert.ToDateTime(fila.Cells("Fecha").Value))
            agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Checada", Convert.ToDateTime(fila.Cells("Checada").Value))
            agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Terminal", Convert.ToDecimal(fila.Cells("Terminal").Value))


            agregar.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Next
        MessageBox.Show("DATOS EXPORTADOS CORRECTAMENTE A SQL")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("OCURRIO UN ERROR EN LA IMPORTACION, FAVOR DE COMUNICARSE CON IT SUPPORT")

    Finally
        conexion.Close()

    End Try


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay un un par de soluciones que puedes implementar.

1-. La variable que llamas contador, puede ser reemplazada por una llave primaria autoincremental. Esta aumentará cada vez que se inserte un registro nuevo en la base de datos.

2-. Para evitar la duplicidad de registros puedes añadir un UNIQUE CONSTRAINT en alguna de tus columnas. Sí el trabajador estará una única vez en la tabla, el valor único puede ser su identificación. Así, no podrás grabar al mismo trabajador dos veces.

3.- Una forma de evitar la duplicidad desde el cliente es desactivando el botón que guarda dentro del evento click, y mantenerlo así hasta recibir confirmación de la base de datos que el registro se guardó. Luego se borran los campos y se habilita el botón nuevamente.

Espero alguno de estos consejos te ayude.

**EDIT:** Lo mejor en este caso es crear una llave compuesta. Se asegura que la combinación "Trabajador-Checada" es única; es decir, que el trabajador 10 sólo puede checar una vez el 23/01/2020 a las 10:01:25.

Imaginando tu tabla, hay dos formas de realizar esto:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Checada
 ADD CONSTRAINT unico_trabajador_checada UNIQUE(trabajador, fecha, checada);
```

o

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unica_checada_trabajador
  ON dbo.Checada(trabajador, fecha, checada);
```

Si no es estrictamente necesario puedes tener la checada de tipo **DATETIME**, la lógica de la descomposición en fecha-hora lo puedes hacer en la aplicación, o utilizando DATEPART en SQL Server.

Comment: Hola Arriel, deja intento la solución 1... el trabajador va estar varias veces en la tabla, lo que cambiara es su checada, en cuestión a la hora solamente, es decir, puede tener 3 registros con 111028 y fecha 23/01/2020 pero la checada sera siempre diferente (07:01:59, 12:01:12, 17:15:41)